# probability - random alumni

Tags: probability

A company has three different sites: Site 1, Site 2 and Site 3.  At Site 1 70% of the employees are NYU alum, at Site 2 20% of the employees are NYU alum, at Site 3 10% are NYU alum.  There are an equal number of employees at each of the three sites.  If an employee is randomly selected for Employee of the Month what is the probability that they are a NYU alum?

Sorry, I know I'm supposed to make an attempt first.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried, or explain what you're having trouble with? Perhaps draw some sort of tree diagram with the possible cases (site $i$, alum / not).

Answer (score 1):

$P(I\cap A) = P(I)\cdot P(A|I) = \dfrac{1}{3}\cdot 0.7$,

$P(II\cap A) = P(II)\cdot P(A|II) = \dfrac{1}{3}\cdot 0.2$,

$P(III\cap A) = P(III)\cdot P(A|III) = \dfrac{1}{3} \cdot 0.1$,

thus: $P(A) = \dfrac{1}{3}\left(0.7+0.2+0.1\right) = \dfrac{1}{3}$